# how to change url at address bar without reloading the page

Tags: php, ajax

I have http://mysite.com/index.php.

And a sub menu

- home => http://mysite.com/index.php
- about us => http://mysite.com/about.us.php
- products => http://mysite.com/products.php

But i want http://mysite.com/index.php to process every request, and just change the content using Ajax request. This way, the site only loads the content part, and is much faster and easy to navigate.

The problem here is SEO, because the only URL google will see is http://mysite.com/index.php and I would like to associate http://mysite.com/about-us to the **About Us** content, http://mysite.com/product to the **Products** content, etc.

I know I can do this with PHP just reading the URL and writing the Ajax on the fly, but doing so the whole page is going to be reloaded every time. 
Is there a way to do this without reloading the whole page?
What I think I need is to have a regular anchor in the submenu, for exampel pointing to "http://mysite.com/contact-us" but when clicked, instead of opening this page, process the Ajax request.

And if this is possible, Google is going to see this as black hat probably, right?

Regards
Alex

Comment: You understand that Ajax doesn't automatically make things faster, right?

Comment: zzzzBov: ????? are you feeling all right? Ajax is the lates buzzword?

Comment: **Working PHP solution**:  `echo "<script>window.history.pushState('', '', 'http://desired.url.here');</script>";` . . . (from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22620697/8112776) buried below.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can't change the URL in the address bar without changing the page because to be able to do that I couldlet you visit me at http://www.imhackingyou.com/sucker but change the addressbar to read http://www.bankofamerica.com/login

Comment: You can, but it's kind a slimy thing to do.

Comment: How can that be the right answer if it's wrong? there is a great answer below that explains how to do what that answer explains you can't!

Answer (score 12):

HERE THERE IS A SOLUTION:

```
window.history.pushState(data, title, url)
```

Here Rob explains how it works, and you have a working example:

http://moz.com/blog/create-crawlable-link-friendly-ajax-websites-using-pushstate

Answer (score 7):

This is a routing issue, not an AJAX issue.

If you were using another tool (*cough* ASP.NET MVC *cough*), you'd just add a route (and I'm hopeful there's a way to do this in PHP) that accepted URLS like

```
/home
/products
...
```

and routed them to, say,

```
/index.php?area=home
/index.php?area=products
```

This is typically accomplished with a rewrite engine when used outside of a good MVC or RESTful URL system. I use [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) on IIS, but if you're working on the LAMP stack, I think Apache provides a module that provides the same capabilities. (Google `.htaccess` )

**WARNING: RANT FOLLOWS**

And, for what it's worth,

1. Avoid trying to write your entire application in JavaScript. The server's there for a reason. Part of your job as a web developer is to absorb as much of the work onto your server as possible. Browser performance and compatibility issues will drive you mad when you try to do everything on the client.
2. Avoiding postbacks makes sense in a lot of circumstances, but it's not a silver bullet that you should try to apply to every page. Usually it makes sense to load a new page when a link is clicked. It's what the user expects, it's more stable (since most of the infrastructure required is server-side) and it's not slower than an AJAX request to retrieve the same thing.

Rules:

1. NEVER break the back button. Without careful planning, most AJAX apps break this rule.
2. See rule #1.

Comment: Thanks David, but its not what i'm asking. I use htaccess rewrite, mostly for SEO purposes. Anyway, I agree with point 1, I find JS+Ajax very useful and sometimes I use it too much. But mainly in CMS, no in the visitor side.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it should be accomplished with a [rewrite engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine), but assuming that you have a good reason to use AJAX, you can change urls with javascript by modifying the portion after the hash, or better yet, the hashbang:

```
window.location.hash = "#!about-us";
```

- http://mysite.com/
- http://mysite.com/#!about-us
- http://mysite.com/#!products

For more info on the hashbang from an SEO perspective, check out http://www.seomoz.org/blog/how-to-allow-google-to-crawl-ajax-content

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to say but I couldn't find the pdf :P

Answer (score 0):

How does Shopify do it then? Go to their website, click on the Features link and you'll see the URL says:

http://www.shopify.com/tour/sell-online

Then click on any of the sub links and you'll see that the address in the URl changes without using a hash but there is no page flip.

I don't think they are using ajax to change the content because it all appears to be included in hidden divs on the page, but regardless, you can apparently change the URL using client side tricks.